# Using the microsoft graph to get calendar information without creating an app registration

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to pull events from teams calendar using microsoft graph.  I wanted to know if there is a way to access graph events without having to create an app registration in azure and then authenticate against that:

```
authResult = await Program.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                    .WithAccount(null)
                    .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
```

Ideally I would like authenticate directly from graph before getting the events and not have to create an app registration:

//Authenticate from microsoft graph without having to create an app registration

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var calendar = await graphClient.Me.Calendar
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();
```

Here is the reference URL of the guide I followed for authenticating using app registration:
https://bytescout.com/blog/microsoft-graph-apis.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a sample and not have to create my own app registration.  Some have mentioned that it could stop working but that is not a problem since this only needs to run once.  Thanks again for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft uses oauth2 for all it's apis. An application is required to get a token, you can create a registration for [free](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app).

Just create your own application registration. This is the way forward.

Edit: previously suggested a way to circumvent the above statement. That is NOT recommended and no one should follow that suggestion

Comment: Hi Stephan, thank you for your feedback.  With the sample you mean you dont have to create your own app registration?  Do you have a link to that source code?

Comment: Don't do this - you're setting yourself up for failure. I've reported the client ID to the maintainers, I suspect they'll delete the app registration, which means your code will stop working. As Stephan says, registering an app is free.

Comment: @Stephan Please remove this guidance to reuse the MSAL.js testing client IDs, thanks.

Comment: @jasonnutter I removed the suggestion, but is the down vote really necessary? I believe it already stated that you should just register an application

Answer (score 0):

Registering your own client ID is a requirement for using the Microsoft Graph. And please do not use other application's client IDs.