# OAuth2 Token on Microsoft Graph API

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking for the most simple way to gain a JWT token to use when calling Graph API endpoints. There is endless documentation about OAuth2 and so many ways to do that, but I got lost in the process.
My scenario is a backend program listening to an Outlook mailbox.

I read about registering my service in Azure AD etc., but I'm looking for something quicker that bypasses everything. I know such solution exists because in the Graph Explorer it is done fairly easily. I only need the JWT token to make the calls work, nothing more.

I tried calling `/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`, but it needs a client_secret which I don't have because I haven't registered my service in Azure. I've tried endlessly to mimic the process that is done in Graph Explorer, but with no luck.

Comment: You have not registered the app?

Comment: You may want to [get it started from the following sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-netcore-daemon) or follow the implementation...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the microsoft graph to get calendar information without creating an app registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67167108/using-the-microsoft-graph-to-get-calendar-information-without-creating-an-app-re)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/67167108/639153 answer is, no shortcuts, just register an application. For a script application I would suggest using the device code flow.

Answer (score 0):

I’m sorry to announce that, but Graph Explorer is an Azure AD registered app by default and you will have no choice but to create an app, this is how Graph API works, and for that, you can follow this link for a non authenticated use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service or this link for calling Graph on behalf of a user https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user